# The optimal way to simulate vision detection from limited visual field

Tags: optimization, real-time, simulation

I need to build an experiment based on a scientific paper in which a high number of agents have a divided visual field (with limited detection distance) and have to detect other agents in a 2D environment.

The visual field angle is evenly divided in N angles. One just need to detect wether there is an agent (or more) or not for each subpart (no need for counting).

As I need to run this simulation many times with many agent I wondered wether there is a software that fits these needs or I should code it by myself.

For the last case I thought of using a chained list for the visual cells (to sort activated and unactivated ones), and use a double loop to test each agent presence in other agents's visual fields.

If you have better ideas I'd be grateful to get some help :) .

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you can find software that fits this task, so you will need to write it yourself. Depending on the number of agents and experiments you need to run, you should either go for simplicity or performance - maybe start with a very simple implementation and optimize after bottlenecks have been identified. A chained list does sound neither simple nor fast :-) Simple bit vectors might be more suitable. If the number of agents is too high for a CPU to handle, you may want to develop for GPU, but only after it is evident that a CPU solution can't be made fast enough.

Comment: Have you looked into [Discrete Event Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEVS)?